# Display SQL query results

Tags: php, sql

I am having trouble displaying results from a SQL query. I am trying to display all images and prices from a products table.

I am able to display the echo statement "Query works" in the browser. But, the results are not displaying in the browser.

```
        if ($count > 0) {
            echo "Query works";
        } else {
            echo "Query doesn't work" ."<br/>";
        }
```

**PHP Code:**

```
$con = getConnection();
        $sqlQuery = "SELECT * from Products";

        // Execute Query -----------------------------           
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sqlQuery);
            if(!$result) {
                echo "Cannot do query" . "<br/>";
                exit;
            }

            $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
            $count = $row[0];

            if ($count > 0) {
                echo "Query works";
            } else {
                echo "Query doesn't work" ."<br/>";
            }

          // Display Results -----------------------------

            $num_results = $result->numRows();

            for ($i=0; $i<$num_results; $i++) {
                $row = $result->fetchRow(MDB2_FETCH_ASSOC);
                echo '<img src="'.$row['Image'].'>';
                echo "<br/>" . "Price: " . stripslashes($row['Price']);
```

}

**Screenshot 1**
[image]
**Screenshot 2: removed the images from the database, and used a filepath instead**

[image]
**Screenshot 3: print_r($row)**

[image]

Comment: Did you try to print the rows you got with print_r($row)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
$sqlQuery = "SELECT * from Products";

        // Execute Query -----------------------------           
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sqlQuery);
            if(!$result) {
                echo "Cannot do query" . "<br/>";
                exit;
            }

            $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
            $count = $row[0];

            if ($count > 0) {
                echo "Query works";
            } else {
                echo "Query doesn't work" ."<br/>";
            }

          // Display Results -----------------------------

            $num_results =mysqli_num_rows($result);

            for ($i=0; $i<$num_results; $i++) {
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($result);
                //print_r($row);
              echo '<img src="'.$row['Image'].'>';
                echo "<br/>" . "Price: " . stripslashes($row['Price']);
            }
```

Comment: @Yogesh i've tried the various solutions suggested, and with yours i was able to display something in the browser--which is a good sign. but right now, the images are showing up as characters. i tried removing the images from the database, and just putting the file path, but in both cases the images display as characters.

Comment: Can you print the row and check whether image path is coming properly or not.

Comment: Array ( [ProductID] => 2 [ProductDescription] => Atheletic Description. [ProductType] => Athletic [Image] => images/shoe_box.jpg [Price] => 100.00 )

Comment: I took a screenshot of what is displayed on my browser when I did print_r($row). The comment above, is only one of the records, the rest are in the screenshot.

Comment: Also noticed that only 4 out of the 9 records in the database are displaying.

Comment: It seems that you have changed datatype from blob to varchar/text. With that last screenshot , paths are coming proper. Just make sure to use absolute path than relative path. currently i guess you are using relative path. If so, just ad necessary path before image . Due to ralative path you are unable to get images or otherwise make sure your relative path is correct.

Answer (score 2):

I think

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$count = $row[0];
```

should be

```
$count = $result->numRows();
if ($count > 0) {
  echo "Query produced $count rows";
} else {
  echo "Query produced no rows" ."<br/>";
  return;
}
```

And your for loop should use [`fetch_assoc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) as:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  echo '<img src="'.$row['Image'].'>';
  echo "<br/>" . "Price: " . stripslashes($row['Price']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

$row is the first result-row (if any) from your query. $row[0] is the first column in this query (which, since you use select *, depends on the order of the columns in your database). So, whether $row[0] > 0 depends on the content of your database.

Answer (score 1):

It's displaying characters because that is how you have stored the image. In order to show the image you are going to have to draw the image with something like:

`echo '<img src="data:image/gif;base64,'.base64_encode($row['Image']).'" />';`

Answer (score 0):

Mysqli doesn't have `fetchRow()`, that's part of the Pear::MDB2 library

See the docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Change your loop to the following:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<img src="'.$row['Image'].'>';
    echo "<br/>" . "Price: " . stripslashes($row['Price']);
}
```

Also, by doing this:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$count = $row[0];
```

before the loop you are essentially skipping the first row and not displaying its image in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

to print all results from a query you can use a while loop

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo 'Price '.$row['Price'].'<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
If ($count > 1)
```

Try

```
If ($count >= 1)
```